# Old Airport Extreme Fails to Reboot When Power Restored After Outage

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I have an old Airport Extreme (the flat one) that has served me well for many years. Right now it sits in a condo that I visit for a few days each month. When I'm not there, the Extreme is used by a couple of wireless Raspberry Pies that run webcams 24/7.

Recently the Extreme has failed to reboot when power is restored after an outage. To get it to start up all I have to do is remove the power plug from the rear panel and put it back. The Extreme boots right up.

Trouble is, I'm usually not there when needed and have to wait until I'm physically present to get the Extreme and the webcams going again.

This only started happening a few months ago, so I'm baffled as to why it is suddenly happening.

Any ideas as to what causes this and what I might do to overcome it?